# Consulta no devuelve los valores esperados

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select 
    Seg.NombreUsuario, count(RelA.IDSeguidor) as `Siguiendo`, count(RelB.IDASeguir) as `Seguidores` 
from Perfiles as Seg 
    inner join Relaciones as RelA on RelA.IDSeguidor = Seg.ID 
    inner join Relaciones as RelB on RelB.IDASeguir = Seg.ID
where Seg.ID = 1
    Group by Seg.NombreUsuario
    Order by Seg.ID
```

Para el siguiente esquema:

```
create table Perfiles
(
    ID int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NombreUsuario varchar(25) not null,
    Clave varchar(25) not null,
    Biografia varchar(300) null,
    Edad int not null default 0,
    Seguidores int not null
);

create table Relaciones
(
    ID int primary key auto_increment,
    IDSeguidor int not null, 
    IDASeguir  int not null, 
    constraint fkIDSeg foreign key (IDSeguidor) references Perfiles(ID) 
    on update cascade on delete cascade, 
    constraint fkIDAs foreign key (IDASeguir) references Perfiles(ID) 
    on update cascade on delete cascade
);
```

Cuando ejecuto la consulta en una tabla que tiene los siguientes valores (He dejado la consulta para que puedan comprobar con los mismos datos de prueba):

```
insert into 
    Perfiles(NombreUsuario, Clave, Biografia, Edad, Seguidores) 
values 
    ('root',      '123456',     'Una biografia 1',        18, 0), 
    ('prueba2',   'valor',      'Otra bio',               16, 0), 
    ('controles', 'contrase;a', 'Biografiaaaaa',          24, 0),
    ('cabello',   'perez34',    'Juanjoseguillermopere"', 30, 0),
    ('mrpelo',    'cebolla20',  'Mr Pelo1',               20, 0),
    ('cabeza1',   'lolololo',   'lololo cabezaaa',        13, 0),
    ('otrouser',  'user10',     'prueba 300',             17, 0),
    ('prueba3',   '123543',     'Prueba 3',               14, 0),
    ('xJeremy',   '13-SISN',    '-6-004 :))',             19, 0),
    ('elultimo',  'elultimo',   'el ultimo',              16, 0);

insert into
    Relaciones(IDSeguidor, IDAseguir)
Values
-- ID 1, sigue al ID 6 y asi...
    (1,6), (3,4), (1,8), (4,1), (5,1), (6,1),
    (5,2), (2,5), (8,1), (1,8), (6,1), (6,3),
    (2,6), (1,9), (9,1), (4,8), (3,7), (7,1),
    (7,3), (5,6), (5,7), (5,8), (8,5), (1,5),
    (9,8), (8,9), (10,1), (1,10), (10,2), (10,3),
    (10,4), (4,10), (8,10), (7,10), (3,10), (10,5),
    (5,10);
```

Me arroja los siguientes resultados:

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| NombreUsuario | Siguiendo | Seguidores |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| root          | 48        | 48         |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

Sin embargo, si ejecuto la siguiente consulta:

```
Select 
    Seg.NombreUsuario, Count(Rel.IDASeguir) as `Siguiendo`
from Relaciones as Rel
    inner join Perfiles as Seg on Rel.IDASeguir = Seg.ID
where Seg.ID = 1
```

Me arroja la cantidad correcta en el campo `Siguiendo` *(6)*.

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que estás contando una vez por cada fila del set de datos resultantes de tus `join`s, cuando deberías contar los valores distintos de `ID` de la tabla relaciones:

```
select 
    Seg.NombreUsuario, 
    count(distinct RelA.ID) as `Siguiendo`, 
    count(distinct RelB.ID) as `Seguidores` 
from Perfiles as Seg 
    inner join Relaciones as RelA on RelA.IDSeguidor = Seg.ID 
    inner join Relaciones as RelB on RelB.IDASeguir = Seg.ID
where Seg.ID = 1
    Group by Seg.NombreUsuario
    Order by Seg.ID;
```

Esto me entrega los siguientes resultados:

```
╔═══════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ NombreUsuario ║ Siguiendo ║ Seguidores ║
╠═══════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ root          ║         6 ║          8 ║
╚═══════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

**[Acá hay](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/615fe/5)** una versión demo de esta consulta.

Comment: `distinct` solo toma los valores distintos, no?

Comment: @NaCl Sí, exacto, lo importante es que son los valores distintos de `ID` de la tabla de `relaciones`, y no del `ID`  de la tabla `perfiles` (en cuyo caso, el resultado sería `1`)